# Inserting special last string of array item into separate array item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

There is an array `test_array` which contains a String split with `.split(' ')`. So the last character of each item can be `'.'`, `'-'`, `'!'` and any other non-word type.
The goal is to insert this character into the array as a separate item after its source and to delete this character from its source.

```
l=0
test_array= @test.source.split(' ') 
test_array. each do |f| 
    if f[-1]== /[^\w]/
        test_array.insert(l+1, f[-1]) 
        f=f.chop 
        l+=1 
    else 
        l+=1 
    end 
end
```

The `/[^\w]/` is regexp of any non-word character.
For some reason it doesn't work. Trying to debug for an hour and no solution.

**UPD**
For example, input is:

**[**"The" "pattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp`;`", "if`:`" **]**

The output should be:

**[**"The" "pattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp"**,** "`;`", "if"**,** "`:`" **]**

Comment: Can you give an example of an input you're giving it, the expected output, and the output you're receiving?

Comment: BTW `\W` is a simpler way to say `[^\w]` in regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Regexp you need to use the `=~` operator, or the `match` method, so your code would become:

(Edit - Thinking about it, you'll get a neverending loop doing this, because you're inserting the non-word character at the end of the array before you've finished iterating, so you will parse the item that you've just inserted, which happens to always be a non-word character .. so you will chop it out and insert it back in.. etc. To fix this, you should build a new array instead, and I have updated my below answer to reflect this.)

```
test_array= @test.source.split(' ') 
result_array=[]
test_array.each do |f| 
    if f[-1]=~ /[^\w]/
        result_array << f.chop << f[-1]
    else
        result_array << f
    end
end
```

Test:

```
1.9.3p194 :041 > test_array = ["The" "pattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp;", "if:" ]
 => ["Thepattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp;", "if:"] 
1.9.3p194 :042 > result_array = []
 => [] 
1.9.3p194 :043 > test_array.each{|f| if f[-1]=~ /[^\w]/; result_array << f.chop; result_array << f[-1]; else; result_array << f; end}
 => ["Thepattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp;", "if:"] 
1.9.3p194 :044 > result_array
 => ["Thepattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp", ";", "if", ":"]
```

*[sauce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html)*

Comment: Thank you very much. I've already found out that loop is infinite by trying to run)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a single [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) using a capture group in your regexp:

```
pry(main)> "The pattern is typically a Regexp; if:".split(/([^\w\s])?(?:\s+|$)/)
=> ["The", "pattern", "is", "typically", "a", "Regexp", ";", "if", ":"]
```

When the split regexp contains capture groups they are returned as well in the result.  This regexp splits on whitespace, capturing an optional non-word/non-whitespace character just prior to the whitespace.

Comment: This is finger-lickin' good.

Comment: Awesome. But can you explain '?' between groups?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace `?` means 0 or one of preceding pattern. `/x?y/` matches y preceded by an optional x.